# Chrome extensions: redirect in context menu

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i have following code in my background.html.

```js
var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create(  {"title": "test '%s'",  "onclick": callLocalhost, "contexts":"selection"]});
function callLocalhost(obj){
    window.location.href="http://localhost/"+obj.selectionText;
}
```

function is called but redirect doesn't work.

window.location.href contains the extension id and is not editable.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Your code executes in the background window of your extension, the `window` object is the background window. To change tab location you need to execute code in the tab. You do it with the [`chrome.tabs.executeScript` method](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript). Something like this (untested):

```js
function callLocalhost(obj, tab){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        code: "var obj = " + JSON.stringify(obj) + ";" +
              "window.location.href='http://localhost/'+obj.selectionText;"
    });
}
```

Note that the content script (the script injected into the tab) cannot access variables of the background window directly. This is why I put `obj` directly into the code to be executed in the tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `chrome.tabs.update` API to change the location:

```js
function callLocalhost(info, tab) {
  chrome.tabs.update(
      info.tab,
      {"url": obj."http://localhost/" + info.selectionText});
}
```

Unlike the `chrome.tabs.executeScript` approach proposed by Wladimir, this doesn't require script execution permissions in the tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [chrome.tabs.create](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create) API.